# RealTime editing PHP files on FTP

Tags: php, ftp, editor, real-time

me, and my partner are working on web project and we constantly working on different PHP functions, and a bunch of functions are in one file, and if someone needs to edit one function and then another, we need to re-download files, well, if we don't inform each other about changes, we lost part of the code, because, other saves files, that they have been downloaded before, so by any chance, is there any editor that would let us edit same file without needing to redownload it for changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a version control system like git or Mercurial. Using it, both can edit the same file without troubles and merge your changes easily.

Never edit a file directly in your FTP. Production code should not be touched this way. Change your code locally and then submit it to your FTP. If you want to avoid headaches, your deploy should be automatic, with a single button click. Read about continuous integration.

Comment: I believe that It's too big for 2 developers, even less than 5.

Comment: On a small team and even solo, the advantage of rollbacks and diff tools is too great to overlook. Git is free, and there are free repo hosts too.

Answer (score 4):

Install WINSCP And a IDE. Visual Studio Code for example.

Connect with WINSCP to your server, rightmouse on a file, config your editor.

When you change and save the file it upload by itself. I work like this for the last 17 year

Answer (score 1):

I have the same scenario, me and my partner adopted Sublime Text + SFTP Extension.

For us it's perfect, when I press Ctrl+S the file is automatically saved to the server (You can change this).

When my partner open the file, the SFTP checks if the version on his computer differs from the version on the server, and asks if he wants to download the new version. (Both Ways)

And have many other features that can be installed with few hotkeys and search..

And the license from both plugin and Sublime Text aren't expensive compared to Many version control systems.

And my friend, when you get used to "multiple editions" with Ctrl+D you will not change your editor anymore.

You can use the free version almost forever until you decide or not to buy.

All you will need:

- [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)
- [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) <- this will lend you a nice GUI to download packages.

Packages I use:

- SFTP (This one will do the magic for you)
- Automatic Backups (Everytime I save a file, the older version is saved in another folder with DateTime stamp for easy rollback).
- Trailing Spaces (Remove the
  trailing spaces reducing the filesize).
- SideBar Enhancements
- SublimeLinter (Sintax Highlight for any language you need [CSS, PHP
  and JS for me])